# How to retrieve a particular image from a scroll view?

Tags: android, android-intent, scrollview

how to retrieve a particular iamge from a scroll view...

in my app i created two Activities .... Activity 1,Activity2 and their corresponding xml1,xml2

```
       ACTIVITY 1:
             package com.scroll;

          import android.os.Bundle;
             import android.app.Activity;
                 import android.content.Intent;
           import android.view.View;
          import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.Button;

             public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act.class);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

                  Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                   b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act.class);
    startActivity(in);

              }
                         });

                      Button b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
                     b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act.class);
    startActivity(in);

               }
                       });
               }
                }
```

ACTIVITY 2:
                       package com.scroll;

```
             import android.os.Bundle;
              import android.app.Activity;

        public class Act extends Activity {

       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

           }

        }


               XML 1:

          <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
               tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <Button
           android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_x="56dp"
           android:layout_y="75dp"
                android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_x="56dp"
                 android:layout_y="75dp"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <Button
                 android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_x="56dp"
                   android:layout_y="75dp"
                     android:text="Button" />

                     </LinearLayout>


            XML 2:

        <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
               android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
               android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
               tools:context=".MainActivity" >

                     <HorizontalScrollView
                   android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_x="-11dp"
                                android:layout_y="-2dp" >

                               <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                     android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="566dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_x="-14dp"
                          android:layout_y="-6dp"
                           android:src="@drawable/bear" />

                                   <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                               android:layout_width="566dp"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                         android:layout_x="-14dp"
                         android:layout_y="-6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/fox" />

                          <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                     android:layout_width="566dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_x="-14dp"
                           android:layout_y="-6dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/goat" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                   </HorizontalScrollView>
```

WEN I SELECT BUTTON 2 , IMAGEVIEW2 SHOULD BE OPENED IN SCROLL VIEW ... AND WEN I SELECT BUTTON 3, IMAGEVIEW3 SHOULD BE OPENED... HOW TO DO THIS...
kindly help me to solve this ....

Comment: Hello, please avoid CAPS, it is bad.

Comment: @LeventeKurusa Indeed. But while you're at it you can also completely remove "please help" and the likes - it's already obvious from asking a question the OP wants help :7

Answer (score 0):

First of all avoid using absolute layout. It is not advisable. Put some classifiers in intent.put extra() , and on the second activity you can retrieve the classifier based on intent.getextra(). Based on that you can switch the visibility of the image view.

For ex:: onclicklistener of button 2 , while launching the intent give intent.put extra("whichButton","button2").
In on create of second activity check 
If(intent.has extra("whichbutton")){String which button= intent.getextra}.
Then based on button values switch visibilty of image views.

Comment: i used as u said but wen i clicks button2.. the scrollview starts from first image(bear).. i need to start the scroll view from second image(fox).... how to achieve tat?

Comment: Calculate the scrollx position and use scrollview.scroll to(scrollx).your scrollx can be the width of imageview1